# Is it acceptable to require a post-doc to teach a course?

Tags: teaching, postdocs

I am an American working on establishing an endowed, permanent post-doctoral fellowship at a university in the UK and am wondering what the usual practices are.

In my case, it would be beneficial to require the fellow to teach a course at the university, but I am wondering if that is acceptable, or whether that will drive away potential candidates that just want to do research. Will having a teaching requirement cause my fellowship to get shunned, or is it a normal thing for fellowships to include a teaching requirement?

Comment: If you and the university are OK with that requirement, then go for it. While it may turn off some post-docs, it would also be a real plus for those that are interested in becoming a professor - they would have clear evidence of being able to teach a real class.

Answer (score 10):

In the UK universities, the pressure to teach is very significant. Postdocs employed on RCUK grants / fellowships are often given an "opportunity" to contribute 20% of their time to teaching. This is not a formal requirement -- they can, of course, reject the opportunity and focus on research. But focusing 100% on research would not necessarily be wise, since their next University is likely to look for candidates with some teaching experience already (unless they move to a different country / sector).

Since it is your fellowship, you can set your own rules to a certain extent. I have heard of PhD studentships with attached duties, e.g. to staff a University museum for a week, etc. It is not unusual for a fellowship / bursary / studentship to come with some strings attached, and it is may be even a good thing to help selecting "right" candidates for the fellowship.